# Format for a timer in AJAX C#

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I currently have a timer event in visual studio in AJAX that is formatted as below:

```
protected void PageTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

I want my output to be displayed as 
    Wednesday, June 3 16:33:21

Just wondering how I could go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime format specifiers can be found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. For your example, "dddd, MMMM d HH:mm:ss" would probably work.

I.e., `CurrentDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM d HH:mm:ss");`